# Save SSL certificate in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, ssl-certificate, jks, p12

I have a `p12` file, which is needed to execute tests.
I added following lines to `system.properties` file.

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\certs\certificate.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=certificate_password
```

It was not working, so I created `jks` file from certificate with `keytool` and set it in the same file.

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\certs\keystore.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=certificate_password
```

I used `CSV Data Set Config` to set also alias, which is used in `Keystore Configuration` component, but not sure, what should be stored in csv data file, how to provide key aliasses. `Options -> SSL Manager` stores certificates until JMeter is closed, doesn't store those permanently.

Answer (score 1):

1. For example you have the csv file holding aliases `aliases.csv` looking like:

   ```
   alias1
   alias2
   alias3
   etc.
   ```
2. So you can add [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read this file and store the alias value into, say `alias` variable

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set]
3. And finally you can use `alias` variable value in the [Keystore Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) which will refer the value of the alias from the CSV file:

   [image: JMeter Keystore with Variable]

More information: [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites)

Comment: Where are path of certificate specified in this case? How are aliases and exact certificates mapped?